# Sub domain valid or not

Tags: subdomain, domain-name

This question may sound stupid.

Theres a certain domain eg abc.com that does not belong to me, so that means I also won't be able to use sub.abc.com? Am I correct with this? So in order to use the abc.com domain I need to own it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you dont. After all you can register xxx.com without owning .com. Technically any owner of a zone (the correct technical term) can put up a mechanism allowing third parties to register sub-zones or manage host entries.

In layman: I may register "hopppaalllaawrralla.com" and if you pay me zillion trillion dollars you can get a.hopppaalllaawrralla.com ;) If you agree. This is how all top level domains operate.

Without that, in practical terms - probably the answer is no.

Comment: So if I can't make an agreement with the owner and I have got no access to the nameservers for that specific domain, I can't do anything with it

Comment: Pretty exactly - that is the whole sense. Imagine what people would do if they could get their hands on microsoft.com ;) you would find "linux.microsoft.com" and "gates-sucks.microsoft.com" within minutes.

Comment: thanx for the answer